# Is there anyway to solve this ODE by hand? Or is numerical integration the only way

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I stumble apon this ODE while learning about ray equations. 
$$\frac{d^2 r(z)}{dz^2} = \frac{b^2r}{b^2r^2-1}$$
where r is a function of z and b is a arbitrary constant.

The article make an approximation that br<<1 such that it reduced to a simple second-order linear differential equation. But I am just wondering if there exists a nice solution to the ODE without this assumption.
Thanks

edit: Sorry typo for the equation and clarified something.

Comment: Does y depend on r, z ?

Comment: What are $r,z$ ? The ODE is hill-posed (without definition of the symbols used). I vote to close it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, type in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that

If $0<x<1$

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$$
$$1+x+o(x)$$

thus if $0<by<1$

$$ \frac{1}{1-b^2y^2}\approx  1+b^2y^2$$

Comment: @CalvinKhor It seem he did not see where the approximation comes from.

Comment: I know where the approximation come from, I am interested in the solution without the approximation

Comment: @MichaelAlpaca You will need two successive integrations. the first will give you some logarithm.

Comment: Yes I have tried that already, it leads me into an integral which can not be integrated, it was something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ln(b^2y^2-1)}}$ or something similar